# Is it possible to select multiple options in a multi-select drop-down with single click or Shift + 'Click'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, multi-select, primereact

We  are using Prime multi-select, we have more than thousand drop-down options there, In which if we want to select 200 out of it we have to select one by one Is there a way to select multiple options in single click or shift + click to select the options? Please let me know your inputs.

Comment: Nope as mentioned in Discord chat use a 1 column Datatable with multiselect and filtering enabled to achieve what you want.